# Распечатать права доступа к выделенной памяти

Tags: c++, c

Выделяю область памяти при помощи malloc и выдаю права этому участку памяти.

```
DWORD old_protect = 0;
int* ptr = (int*)malloc(1000);
int test = VirtualProtect(ptr, 1000, 0x40, &old_protect);
```

Как я могу посмотреть какие права у памяти на текущий момент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Этот код не будет работать, так как первым аргументов для `VirtualProtect` должен идти указатель на первую страницу в регионе памяти, а не какой-то рандомный указатель, возвращенный `malloc`.
- Для просмотра информации по правам памяти есть функция `VirtualQueryEx`.